# No wi-fi adaptor found and trackpad isn't working

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, wifi-direct

Today I dualbooted win11 and ubuntu and I faced two problems which is the wifi adaptor not being recognised and trackpad isn't working. I am using a hp laptop and I believe wifi adaptor is built in (I'm not a techy)

Comment: Please ask a separate question regarding each issue.

Comment: The problem with dual-booting with Win11 is that it became mandatory to have Secure Boot enabled. Disabling it would probably solve at least the WiFi problem if not both. But you can't disable it now so it needs a different and lot more involved procedure. Please do as above as ask separated questions, with both `lspci` and `lsusb` results.